# How do I edit the actual content of this TYPO3 plugin object?

Tags: magento, typo3

I've inherited a site using TYPO3 and I don't have that much experience with it.  I have a page with a left column in the layout.  In that left column is an object using an "insert" plugin.  On the actual page is a graphic map.  I'm just wondering how to edit the actual content that this is referring to.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here it is a bit more zoomed in...

[image]

Based on all of the meta-data this is some kind of "Magento"/"Insert" plugin being used.  Again, the question is, where do I edit/change the actual content associated with this object?

If I click on the plugin icon to the left of the "Magento Left" label and select "edit", this is what I get:

[image]

Clicking the "Plugin" tab gives me this:

[image]

HELP!

Comment: 1000th Magento question - woo!  sorry, can't help you with Typo3 tho!

Answer (score 0):

My guess (and it is a guess, since I've never used Magento before) is that you can't, at least not through the TYPO3 backend.  The Magento plugin is probably creating the output itself and then piping it into the plugin directly.  So to alter the output you'd need to go into the Magento plugin's source code and edit that.

Answer (score 0):

I have also not used this particular extension, but you might have success in clicking the plugin icon just to the left of the "Magento Left" title. At any rate, if this is the plugin called "Magento", it seems to be simply a bridge for content from somewhere else, and the displayed content should then probably be edited somewhere else. All speculation here. Further info about the plugin might be obtained from
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/fb_magento/current/.

Comment: Hello again, the content source seems to be available if you open the Extension Manager, make sure "Loaded extensions" is active in the top left of the content pane. Look for Magento and click the name to the right of the icon. This is where the plugin is configured; you will see the URL of the shop where the content is fetched from, username and password (don't screenshot them here!), and various other stuff which I know nothing about (but has something to do with the operation of the plugin).

Comment: You don't need to edit the configuration (indeed, you shouldn't), but these are your credentials for editing the content in the actual shop (for which the TYPO3 installation is purely a display mechanism). From your screenshots (CODE) you seem to need to search for the keyword "left". Hope this helps.